# Interpolate specific columns of data

Tags: import, interpolation

I have a txt file with 3 columns of data:

x      y1     y2

How do I import the file then create 2 functions, one interpolated with {x,y1} values and the other interpolated with {x,y2} values?

This is the sort of thing I want to achieve (in pseudocode):

```
Import "data.txt" into A
f1 = Interpolation(A,{x,y1})
f2 = Interpolation(A,{x,y2})
```

Comment: Did you happen to look up the `Import` documentation? [This](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) and its subpage on basic formats (search for "Table") would be a good starter.`Interpolation` also has a very readable [doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html). To get the table you obtain after importing into separate columns, you need [Transpose](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html). Please, try to reach a minimum proficiency level of the language by reading the documentation before asking questions.

Comment: For taking parts of arrays you could check out the documentation of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
a = Transpose[Import["data.txt", "Table"]];

f1 = Interpolation[{a[[1]], a[[2]]} // Transpose];
f2 = Interpolation[{a[[1]], a[[3]]} // Transpose];
```

might work?

Alternatively,

```
a = Import["data.txt", "Table"];

f1 = Interpolation[Drop[#, {3}] & /@ a];
f2 = Interpolation[Drop[#, {2}] & /@ a];
```

or even

```
f1 = Interpolation[ a[[All, {1, 2}]] ];
f2 = Interpolation[ a[[All, {1, 3}]] ];
```

Comment: For the second one, you can also use `a[[All,{1,2}]]` and `a[[All, {1,3}]]` instead of `Drop[...]&/@a`.

Comment: Thanks, but only the first method worked for me